# OnClientClick and Calling Custom JavaScript Function

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following code to call a javascript function but the OnClientClick expression is never evaluated.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
OnClientClick='moveComment(txtComment_<%# Eval("Container.DataItemIndex") %>)'
runat="server" Text="add comment"/>
```

Comment: Edited code to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: from what it looks like the way you have your button set up it is calling a javascript function and not a codebehind method correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick='<%#    
GetId(Container.DataItemIndex.ToString()) %>' runat="server" Text="add comment"/>
```

And GetId method on the server side:

protected string GetId(string index)
        {
            return "moveComment('txtComment_"+ index +"')"; 
        }

Comment: where are you calling this GetId method from?

Comment: I just added it for you, just noticed you left the rest of the code out

Comment: @azamsharp - accept your own answer here, so that this question doesn't show up in the site as *unanswered*

Answer (score 1):

```cs
OnClientClick='<%# "GetId(" +Container.DataItemIndex.ToString()+  "); " %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding "return false;" to your OnClientClick expression will solve your problem.  This will prevent the button from making a postback but will still execute your client side javascript function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick='moveComment(txtComment_<%# Eval("Container.DataItemIndex") %>); return false;' runat="server" Text="add comment"/>
```